# playframework 2.0 scala - No suitable driver found in tests

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

I was following [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-play-21-scala) tutorial to star using playframework2.1 RC1 + Slick.

When try launch the SoftwareSpec test (that tests Model-like class):

play test

they fail with an error like this:

> [error]     SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:h2:mem:test1 (DriverManager.java:190) [error]
>   SoftwareSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(SoftwareSpec.scala:25)
>   [error]
>   SoftwareSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(SoftwareSpec.scala:25)

But I've enabled h2 db in application.conf like was mentioned in that article.

I've used latest dependencies to slick, in Build.scala file:

"`com.typesafe" % "slick_2.10.0-RC1" % "1.0.0-RC1"`

Once, when I changed dependency to slick to this version:

```
"com.typesafe" % "slick_2.10.0-RC1" % "0.11.2"
```

then the test was passed successfully. But after I change the test to make it fail, the error came back again - "No suitable driver". And after this all my tries (like play clean whatever) were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when running tests on Travis CI.

A work around is loading JDBC driver class like `Class.forName("org.h2.Driver")`.

https://github.com/seratch/scalikejdbc/blob/564cc07505d7a9f217945a7f2c07dc2c7460ed87/scalikejdbc-play-plugin/src/test/scala/scalikejdbc/PlayPluginSpec.scala#L15

Of course, I should investigate the reason of this issue and report to the Play team but I haven't done.

Comment: I had to go further and call `DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.h2.Driver)`, as suggested here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalikejdbc-users-group/u61NXZM6pYU/5dvs6mLt0m8J

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Play at the moment, so I can't test the following, but it should be fine. For the latest Slick, you can use:

```
"com.typesafe" % "slick_2.10" % "1.0.0-RC1"
```

For h2, the following should work:

```
"com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.166"
```